# Get names of multiple servers SSMS is connected to

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one instance of SSMS open and I am connected to one remote server as well as localhost.  How can I get the names of all the servers that SSMS is currently connected to?  The emblem of the remote server looks like 
[image]

and the local looks like 
[image]

Also, I would like to know if there's any problems with connecting to multiple servers from one instance of SSMS, and how to switch between servers through a script without clicking on a table name and doing something like `select top 1000 rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there are multiple issues at work here as this is not always a simple answer.  Depending on your environment and rights you may have one or more many permission groups that have access to one or many environments which have one or many servers that thus have access to one or many databases.  However if you do have permission and you have linked servers set up with data access you can do something like this to get a listing of things you have access to.  You could run this similarly on different environments making it into a procedure that you could call with ADO.NET or similar.

```
--declare variable for dynamic SQL
DECLARE 
    @SQL    NVARCHAR(512)
,   @x      int


-- Create temp table to catch linked servers
Declare @Servers TABLE
    (
        Id          int identity
    ,   ServerName  VARCHAR(128)
    )

-- insert linked servers
insert into @Servers
select name
FROM sys.servers

-- remove temp table if it exists as it should not be prepopulated.
IF object_ID('tempdb..#Databases') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE tempdb..#Databases
;

-- Create temp table to catch built in sql stored procedure
CREATE TABLE #Databases --DECLARE @Procs table 
    (
        ServerName      varchar(64)
    ,   DatabaseName    VARCHAR(128)
    )

SET @X = 1

-- Loops through the linked servers with matching criteria to examine how MANY there are.  Do a while loop while they exist.
WHILE @X <= (SELECT count(*) FROM @Servers)
BEGIN
    declare @DB varchar(128);

    Select @DB = ServerName from @Servers where Id = @X  -- get DB name from current cursor increment

    -- Set up dynamic SQL but do not include master and other meta databases as no one cares about them.
    SET @SQL = 'insert into #Databases select ''' + @Db + ''', name from ' + @DB + '.master.sys.databases
                where name not in (''master'',''tempdb'',''model'',''msdb'')'

    -- Execute the dynamic sql to insert into collection object
    exec sp_executesql @SQL

    -- increment for next iteration on next server
    SET @X = @X + 1
END
;

SELECT *
FROM #Databases
```

Comment: this is an extensive, well-thought out answer.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  If you are asking if you can connect to multiple instances of SQL Server in a single query window the answer is yes.  I went into detail on how and some of the implications here: [Multiple instances, single query window](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/02/18/multiple-instances-single-query-window/)

If on the other hand you are asking how to tell what instance you are connected to you can use `@@SERVERNAME`.

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

It will return the name of the instance you are connected to.

Typically you would connect to one instance per query window and flip between the windows to affect the specific instance you are interested in.

If you want to write a command to send you to a specific instance you can set your query window to `SQLCMD` mode (Query menu -> SQLCMD Mode) and use the `:CONNECT` command.

```
:CONNECT InstaneName
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

Comment: Say for instance I have two connections, one local and one remote.  The dropdown list of available databases (near the New Query button in SSMS) will only show databases available to a particular instance.  If I go to a different instance and expand the databases folder, the tables folder and then right click and select `select top 1000 rows` the connection automatically changes.  How is that does via script?

Comment: You are looking at two different things.  The part on the left is the object explorer, the right is the query window.  You have connections in the object explorer, and connections in the query window.  When you right click and select `select top 1000 rows` you are creating a new connections on the right side.  The connection isn't changing.  You are opening a new one.